# Webpack provided dependency dooms my app to a circular dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I included some external library in my web app and started to build it with Webpack (5.45.1), that old good error came up: `Cannot read property <..> of undefined`. Getting into the weeds, I found out the issue is a circular dependency. The external library requests Node.js `util` one and the subsequent dependency graph looks in such way:

`./node_modules/util/util.js -> node_modules/console-browserify/index.js -> ./node_modules/assert/build/assert.js -> ./node_modules/assert/../assertion_error.js -> ./node_modules/util/util.js`

As it turns out, `util` requests `console-browserify` before exporting something and `assert` needs `util` export stuff, hence that error.

Moreover, the original `util.js` package is not dependent on the `console-browserify` at all, it was injected to there by Webpack in the following way:

```
/* provided dependency */ var console = __webpack_require__(/*! ./node_modules/console-browserify/index.js */ "./node_modules/console-browserify/index.js");
```

How can I address this issue? Why does Webpack introduce this dependency?

Comment: I don't see the package [util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util) depend on console-browserify, and [console-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-browserify) also doesn't depend on assert, infact, it has 0 dependencies. Try running `npm ls --depth=Infinity`, what do you get as an output?

Comment: Actually, this might give you a seriously long output, for this loop we only need a depth of 5, so `npm ls --depth=5` should be good enough.

Comment: @Quantalabs indeed, `console-browserify` is declaratively dependent on nothing, but its actual code contains `var assert = require("assert")` statement. I'm not aware of reasons of this behavior.

Comment: @Quantalabs I forgot `assert` is a core Node.js package.